# Bash - only printing certain parts of a matrix using awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I want to read a matrix of numbers

```
1 3 4 5 
2 4 9 0
```

And only want my awk statement to print out the first and last, so 1 and 0. I have this so far, but nothing will print. What is wrong with my logic?

```
    awk 'BEGIN {for(i=1;i<NF;i++)
        if(i==1)printf("%d ", $i);
        else if(i==NF && i==NR)printf("%d ", $i);}'
```

Comment: `i` is never both equal to `NF` and `NR`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk '{ if (NR==1) { print $1}} END{print $NF}' matrix
1
0
```

The above awk program has two parts.  The first is:

```
{ if (NR==1) { print $1}}
```

This prints the first field (column) of the first record (line) of the file.

The second part is:

```
END{print $NF}
```

This parts runs only at the end after the last record (line) has been read.  It prints the last field (column) of that line.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR==1{print $1;} END{print $NF;}'
```

Comment: A great answer would have an explanation in addition to code. Your answer provides no extra information compared to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from [unix.com](http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/215805-awk-print-first-row-forth-column-last-row-fifth-column-each-file.html), you can use the following:

```
awk 'NR == 1 {print $1} END { print $NF }'
```

This will print the first column of the first line (NR == 1) and end input has finished (END), print the final column of the last line.

If I understand the output format you're looking for, this code should capture those values and print them:

```
awk 'NR == 1 {F = $1} END { L = $NF ; printf("%d %d", F, L) }'
```

Answer (score 1):

awk is line based, NR is the **current** record (line) number.
and awk is essentially match => action,

```
echo "1 3 4 5
2 4 9 0" |
awk 'NR == 1 {print $1;}
    END {print $NF;}'
```

for the first record print the first field;
for the last record print the last field.

Answer (score 1):

Since so many solutions with awk, here is another way with sed.

```
sed -r ':a;$!{N;ba};s/\s+.*\s+/ /' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another `sed` variant:

```
$ echo $'1 3 4 5\n2 4 9 0' | sed -n '1s/ .*//p;$s/.* //p'
```